# infinispan cache object update in transaction roll back issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, infinispan

we hope to use infinispan as a in memory data base in the order management system. There we need to do following type of operation. Here cash account cache contain customer cache account loaded from DB.  Say initial balance of the cash account1 is 1000 and cashAccount2 is 2000. we update both cash account in a transaction in a jboss 7.1 application server. what we expect as a result is balances of the both cash account remain without changing since this operation occurred inside the transaction. But unfortunately it even after transaction roll back we can see the update object in side the cache. ut
what we examine is when we add a object to the cache in side a transaction when the transaction roll back it will remove from the cache. But modification of the existing object remain as it is.

This is just a sample what we want to do. Actual one involve updating several object in a single transaction.

Could you please let us know it is possible to use infinispan for this type of opperation.

```
cashAccountCache= provider.getCacheContainer().getCache(CACHE_NAME);
        try {
            utx.begin();
            CashAccount cashAccount1 = cashAccountCache.get("cashAccNumber1");
            CashAccount cashAccount2 = cashAccountCache.get("cashAccNumber2");
            cashAccount1.setBalance( cashAccount1 .getBalance() + 100);
            cashAccount2.setBalance( cashAccount2 .getBalance() + 200);
             if(true) throw new RuntimeException();
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (utx != null) {
                try {
                    utx.rollback();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe the cache is configured to be non-transactional? By default, caches are non-transactional. You need to make them transactional explicitly (see cache configs in AS7 configuration file). This looks to be some sort of set up issue.

Comment: Are'nt you trying to directly modify the value stored in map without the cache knowing about it?

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this in infinispan is to make to CacheAccount object immutable.
Otherwise you are changing the property of an object, and Infinispan has no control of it.

```
//CashAccount Class
public class CashAccount{

    public CashAccount setBalance(int balance){
        CacheAccount account = new CacheAccount(this); //deep copy
        account.setBalance(balance);
        return account;
    }

}



cashAccountCache= provider.getCacheContainer().getCache(CACHE_NAME);
try {
    utx.begin();
    CashAccount cashAccount1 = cashAccountCache.get("cashAccNumber1");
    CashAccount cashAccount2 = cashAccountCache.get("cashAccNumber2");
    cashAccount1 = cashAccount1.setBalance( cashAccount1 .getBalance() + 100);
    cashAccount2 = cashAccount2.setBalance( cashAccount2 .getBalance() + 200);
    cacheAccountCache.put("cashAccNumber1", cashAccount1);
    cacheAccountCache.put("cashAccNumber2",cacheAccount2);
    if(true) throw new RuntimeException();
    utx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (utx != null) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
    }
}
```